# Encasing electrical outlet behind a panel above overhead microwave

Tags: electrical

My remodeling contractor has installed an overhead microwave.  The electrical outlet is no longer in a cabinet above the microwave.  He has taken the limited space above the microwave ( about 8 inches of clearance) and has the electrical outlet encased inside with a panel across the top of the microwave.

Is this safe?  Certainly not practical in my mind.  Should I ever have microwave repair needed, I will have to dismantle his carpentry work to get inside the space to the outlet.

Comment: A photo might be useful.  If there is an "easily" removable panel, this might be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The electrical outlet always needs to be accessible. Electrical code in regions that I know about do not permit an electrical box, then yet an outlet attached to it, to be buried behind permanent structure.

It sounds like your remodeling contractor does not know his way around an electrical issue.

Comment: I might not be too quick to judge, without actually seeing the installation myself. *Accessible* is a very blurry term, with lots of grey areas.

Comment: ... for example, outlets for electric stoves and dishwashers are typically accessed by pulling out the machine.

As long as there's a sufficiently large opening allowing access to the outlet, and it can be reached when necessary for service of the machine, it may be fine.